# let: bad syntax (missing binding pairs or body)

Tags: scheme

I would like to declare three lists on which to do operations, but using `define` their value does not change. So I thought I'd use `let` but it gives me an error.

```
(let ((A '0)
      (B '0)
      (C '0)
      )
  )
```

I expect 3 lists but it gives me this error:

```
let: bad syntax (missing binding pairs or body) in: (let ((A (quote 0)) (B (quote 0)) (C (quote 0))))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't change"? How do you try to change them?

Comment: `'0` is not a list. If you want an empty list, write `'()`. (I sense from your wanting to "do operations" on these lists so that their values "change" that you're already barking up the wrong tree by thinking imperatively. There are [good](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) [books](https://htdp.org) and [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Op3QLzMgSY&list=PLE18841CABEA24090) available for free.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scm
(let ((a 0) (b 0) (c 0))
  ;; a, b, c lives inside this let block
  (list a b c)) ;; a body of the let that makes a list (0 0 0)

;; a, b, c from the let block no longer exist
```

The Scheme report expect you to use the binding for something. Thus after you have defined the bindings of the let it is expected that there is at least one expression inside it that does something. The `let` is just syntax sugar for this:

```scm
;; anonymous lambda call
((lambda (a b c)
   (list a b c))  ;; body of the lambda that makes list (0 0 0)
 0 ; a
 0 ; b
 0); c
```

Now imagine what this is supposed to do:

```scm
;; anonymous lambda call
((lambda (a b c)
  ;; no body that does anything 
  )
 0 ; a
 0 ; b
 0); c
```

Answer (score 1):

writing `let` with no body is the same as defining a lambda function with no body.

```
(let ((A '0)
      (B '0)
      (C '0)
      )
  )
```

is the same as writing

```
(lambda(a b c) ) 0 0 0) ;; here it is not allowed to define function with no statement inside
```

('0 is evaluated to itself).

Answer (score 0):

You did it right but there was code missing

```
(let ((A '0)
      (B '0)
      (C '0)
      )
  you need code here
  )
```